Coldbox app runs fine in root dir when starting server, but not in subdir on destination server
I feel like I am missing something very basic.
I have an application, the sample MyPlayground application, which I've been following through the tutorial.
The application works correctly when I start the server from commandbox, all the handlers, etc. and views work fine.  Example, hitting this: http://127.0.0.1:63157/ brings up the default view as expected.
Hitting /Main brings up the main/index view, as expected.
On our servers, we run ColdFusion on Windows, with IIS as the webserver. My laptop is configured this way.
Hitting my installed Adobe Coldfusion server through IIS on my local machine (laptop): http://localhost/MyPlayground brings up the default view as expected.
Hitting http://localhost/MyPlayground/Main results in 404 http error from IIS. It indicates that the requested URL is:  http://localhost/MyPlayground/Main
IIS is suggesting that the Requested URL was:  http://localhost:80/MyPlayground/Main, and the Physical Path was: c:\wwwroot\MyPlayground\Main.
From what I understand, this should just work.
I tried using the web.config and the url rewrite module, and I followed the example rewrites from Ortus documentation.
With the url rewrites active, the same problem occurs, but the error is this instead: http://localhost:80/index.cfm/MyPlayGround/Main and the Physical Path is: C:\wwwroot\index.cfm\MyPlayGround\Main
Any help with this would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,
Allen
Placed the folder of the coldbox application in the wwwroot (c:\wwwroot\MyPlayground).
Browsed http://localhost/Myplayground, and then http://localhost/Myplayground/Main
Expected main.index view, but instead received IIS error.

I should have mentioned that I am using Adobe ColdFusion 2023, with IIS 10.0 running on Windows 10, with the latest version of Coldbox installed via CommandBox.

It turns out that my issue was simply the rewrite rule.  There are example rewrite rules on the ortus website, and they work fine as long as you put the web.config with the rules into the directory of the coldbox application and not at the root of the webserver itself.


Hitting http://ourServer/localhost/Main results in 404 http error from IIS

What is ourServer? Is it your domain name? If so, then this is conflicting with localhost.
You can try to access http://ourServer to see if it works properly. If not, you need to configure ourServer in IIS.

Sorry, that was a typo that I have corrected.  I had meant to use localhost as the example.

You need more information to analyze your problem, try using failed request tracing to see details about 404 error, this will generate detail log file, which will help you to identify the problem.
